# How to enable gzip compression and leverage browser caching in odoo-11 window deployment?

Tags: windows, deployment, gzip, odoo, odoo-11

I just install odoo 11 in my windows 10 computer and was really simple, but now I want to enable gzip compression and leverage browser caching and I don't have any idea how to do that. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser caching is used by default; the Odoo `web` application structure supports this. Browser caching is used for any non-session-specific files, like CSS, JS etc., which are bundled on the Odoo server side.

gz-compression is not used by default.
If you want to use this, you'll have to use a proxy web server (eg. Apache or nginx) before your Odoo server.
For a sample configuration and detailed description, see the https setup guide: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/setup/deploy.html#https-proxy

This is really worth the trouble only for a production setup; a development or demo system on a workstation or laptop is usually not worth it.